# wso2 identity server - sending email when user changed password

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I am using WSO2 IS 5.3.0 server and I am wondering if it is possible to send an email when user changes his password or any other attribute, etc., email.? Is this feature already built in WSO2 IS (I couldn't find anything in WSDL services) or is it then possible to extend something?

Any comments about this issue would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Please do the following steps to achieve this task.

- Write a custom user operation event listener extending the [AbstractUserOperationEventListener.java](https://github.com/wso2/carbon-kernel/blob/v4.4.11/core/org.wso2.carbon.user.core/src/main/java/org/wso2/carbon/user/core/common/AbstractUserOperationEventListener.java)
- Implement the doPostUpdateCredential method. [doPostUpdateCredential](https://github.com/wso2/carbon-kernel/blob/4.4.x/core/org.wso2.carbon.user.core/src/main/java/org/wso2/carbon/user/core/listener/UserOperationEventListener.java#L119)
- Trigger notification event handler to send a notification to the user. [EventHandlerNotification](https://github.com/wso2-extensions/identity-governance/blob/v1.0.2/components/org.wso2.carbon.identity.recovery/src/main/java/org/wso2/carbon/identity/recovery/password/NotificationPasswordRecoveryManager.java#L238)

Comment: where should we add this code?